# Time complexity for BFS/DFS using adjacency list

Tags: graph

Its O(n+m) where n=no. of nodes and m=no. of edges.
It cannot be O(m) alone becoz while visiting every edge nodes are also visited in the process

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Why are we adding no. of nodes in time complexity because while  exploring edges nodes are covered can u give me a eg of graph where not involving no. of nodes in complexity makes a difference

Comment: In a graph which has one connected component with edges and many isolated nodes, the respective algorithms also have to visit the isolated nodes. As the number of isolated nodes grows, it eventually dominates the number of edges.

Comment: BFS/DFS explores nodes and finds path connected to source node(which is passed as parameter) .So nodes isolated from source node does not make any difference